# Posting Tweets Works on Some Devices

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j in Android. I have some weird instance wherein I can post tweets successfully in my Sony Experia phone while cannot post in my Samsung Galaxy Tab and S4. The logcat says,

```
06-09 14:07:53.602: W/DefaultRequestDirector(22501): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
06-09 14:07:53.610: E/sample.app.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(22501): OAuth - Access Token Retrieval Error
06-09 14:07:53.610: E/sample.app.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(22501): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException: Authorization failed (server replied with a 401). This can happen if the consumer key was not correct or the signatures did not match.
```

Some say it is because of the wrong date in the phone but I looked at my phone's date and the time is right. So what is wrong with this? Hope you could help me. Thank you.

Comment: anyone who experienced same situation?